# Security context of a new process started from windows service C#

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, service, process

I have a windows service that runs under a logon say "UserA". The job of the windows service is to start a new process on a timer elapsed event.

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartNewProcess());
}

private void Initialize()
{
    newProcess = new Process();
    newProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Test.exe";
    newProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "sessionId...";
    newProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    newProcess.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
    newProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    newProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    newProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    newProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;            
}

private void StartNewProcess()
{
    newProcess.Start();
}
```

On task manager I see that both the windows service and the new process have a "User Name" as "UserA".

But the problem is Windows service is able to access "C:\QueryResult"  but the new process is not able to access "C:\QueryResult"

I am using `File.Copy("C:\QueryResult", "D:\blahblah")` on both the process

Has the security context changed in the new process?

Comment: Have you tried logging, either to a file or the event log, the security context of the process?

Comment: I get UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "C:\QueryResult" is denied.

Comment: Habo - Yes tried logging in the current thread Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name Interesting that in windows service the name is "UserA" and in the new process Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name is emtpy.

Answer (score 0):

Try automatically elevating the application permissions like so:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        if (!IsAdmin() && IsWindowsVistaOrHigher())
            RestartElevated();
        else
            DoStuff();
    }

    private static Boolean IsAdmin()
    {
        WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

        if (identity != null)
            return (new WindowsPrincipal(identity)).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);

        return false;
    }

    private static Boolean IsWindowsVistaOrHigher()
    {
        OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
        return ((os.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT) && (os.Version.Major >= 6));
    }

    private static void RestartElevated()
    {
        String[] argumentsArray = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        String argumentsLine = String.Empty;

        for (Int32 i = 1; i < argumentsArray.Length; ++i)
            argumentsLine += "\"" + argumentsArray[i] + "\" ";

        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();

        info.Arguments = argumentsLine.TrimEnd();
        info.CreateNoWindow = false;
        info.ErrorDialog = false;
        info.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
        info.RedirectStandardError = true;
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.Verb = "runas";
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
        info.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

        try
        {
            Process.Start(info);
        }
        catch { return; }

        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```